# Changing webview color depending on url

Tags: android, webview

Basically I have a webview app, now I must say I DO know how to change the color of it.

We all know of the white flash when navigating etc, and we all know how to fix that. However fixing that and navigating to another site with minimal styling, inherits my webview color, which I don't want.

What I'm after is to keep the webview color, say black, but when tapping on said site have it like a untouched background (default white).

Possible?

Any information is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, I did end up figuring this out.

In:

```
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//Added this:
WebView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_switch));
}
```

Then in:

```
      @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    WebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }
```

and..

```
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

  WebView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_switch));
}
```

Seems to have fixed wheat I was trying to do. A little lag displaying the white background on load, but it works. Hope this helps others.